# Getting two inputs in one line, and how to let the code run even if the user gives only one input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use one line to get multiple inputs, and if the user only gives one input, the algorithm would decide whether the input is a negative number. If it is, then the algorithm stops. Otherwise, the algorithm loops to get a correct input.

My code:

```py
integer, string = input("Enter an integer and a word: ")
```

When I try the code, Python returns

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I tried "try" and "except", but I couldn't get the "integer" input. How can I fix that?

Comment: use `input("Enter an integer and a word: ").split()`

Comment: @eyllanesc I think I am supposed to get two inputs in one line, and if I only get one input, the algorithm can decide whether it is a negative number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get two inputs at a time, you can use [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). Just like the following example :

```
x = 0
while int(x)>= 0 :
    try :
        x, y = input("Enter a two value: ").split() 
    except ValueError:
        print("You missed one")
    print("This is x : ", x) 
    print("This is y : ", y)
```

Comment: You mean it does not work when you input a single value? What is the error you are getting now?

Comment: @user398843 Do you mean like a while loop that checks the x value ?

Comment: I think while loop does not work. If you only provide one value to your algorithm, you get an error, so you cannot use while loop to check.

Comment: Check out the edit, tell me if that fits what you need. The program keeps asking the user for two values but stops when the first one is negative.

Comment: If I give only one input, the it still returns ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1). And this is why I'm seeking a help

Comment: Why do you give only one input ? Give it two and if the first one is not negative it will keep asking.

Comment: That's a question from my professor.. I wish I could decide what the algorithm would be

Comment: I used a try/except to handle the exception however that still requires two values in input.

Comment: Check if you can convert one of the inputs to an int/float by try/except. After that assign the values. If you can't convert it, it must be just a string...

Comment: You should move the `print`s inside the `try`. If there were not enough inputs, the `print` lines might raise an error

Answer (score 0):

I believe the implementation below does what you want.

The program exits only if the user provides a single input which is a negative number of if the user provides one integer followed by a non-numeric string.

```
userinput = []

while True:
    userinput = input("Enter an integer and a word: ").split()
    # exit the program if the only input is a negative number
    if len(userinput) == 1:
        try:
            if int(userinput[0]) < 0:
                break
        except:
            pass
    # exit the program if a correct input was provided (integer followed by a non-numeric string)
    elif len(userinput) == 2:
        if userinput[0].isnumeric() and (not userinput[1].isnumeric()):
            break
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55341028